# Checking if JSON key is empty

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'd like to be able to check if a JSON key is empty, then have the script exit depending on the result.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "results": []
}
```

If the "results" key is empty, as it is above, I want the script to exit with a return code of 0, otherwise it should return 1.

I've tried

```
import json, sys

obj=json.load(sys.stdin)

if obj["results"]=="":
    exit(0)
else:
    exit(1)
```

But this produces:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `if not 'results' in obj`? Which I guess becomes `sys.exit(int(not 'results' in obj))` - I'm a bit confused where the title of your question fits into this - so I'm not sure what answer you're really after.

Comment: The code you posted can't throw that exception. Please include a valid [MCVE] with full traceback.

Comment: And note that for the given JSON, `obj['result']` will produce `[]`, not `""`, so the condition fails.

Comment: Sorry, I confused it with another question that I was going to post, will update title

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check both, the key existence and its length:

```
import json, sys

obj=json.load(sys.stdin)

if not 'results' in obj or len(obj['results']) == 0:
    exit(0)
else:
    exit(1)
```

Comment: `if not obj.get('results'):` would be far more concise. However, the question is unclear, as there is *no list access in the question* so the exception makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you, this solution with @MartijnPieters modification works

Answer (score 1):

```
import json, sys

obj=json.load(sys.stdin)

if len(obj["results"])==0:
    exit(0)
else:
    exit(1)
```

try using the length of obj["results"]

Comment: Where the key doesn't exist, you won't have an object to check the length against - so this will produce the same error as the OP is currently receiving.

Comment: @JonClements - that's exactly why I'm here... I keep running into that exact issue...