# Python: if-else statement in for loop, remove for variable from list

Tags: python, json, api, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to update values based off an API call on a server. I have a list of IDs that I have pulled from a previous call saved in a list. I am iterating through the 4 values in the list and doing a new API call to grab some alerts in JSON. If the part of the JSON I'm looking for is blank I want the loop to continue but if there is a value then I want it to find and replace text so I can use it on the next step to do a PUT API call.

I can't figure out why the loop continues to give me ALL of the values.

My code:

```
site_ids = []
for ids in parsed['resources']:
    site_ids.append((ids['id']))
```

This gives me a list of [6, 5, 7, 1] which I then use in my next API call to get the alerts

```
for sid in site_ids:
    smtp_url = "my url"+str(sid)+"API endpoint"
    smtp_payload={}
    smtp_headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'my stuff'
    }

    smtp_response = requests.request("GET", smtp_url, headers=smtp_headers, data=smtp_payload, verify=False)
    smtp_text = smtp_response.text
    smtp_json = json.loads(smtp_text)

    print(json.dumps(smtp_json["resources"], indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

This gives me the results for each JSON

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test1",
        "notification": "SMTP",
        "recipients": [
            "abc@abc.com"
        ],
        "relayServer": "1.2.3.4",
        "senderEmailAddress": "test@abc.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test2",
        "notification": "SMTP",
        "recipients": [
            "abc@abc.com"
        ],
        "relayServer": "1.2.3.4",
        "senderEmailAddress": "test@abc.com"
    }
]
[
    {
        "name": "Test3",
        "notification": "SMTP",
        "recipients": [
            "abc@abc.com"
        ],
        "relayServer": "1.2.3.4",
        "senderEmailAddress": "test@abc.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test4",
        "notification": "SMTP",
        "recipients": [
            "abc@abc.com"
        ],
        "relayServer": "1.2.3.4",
        "senderEmailAddress": "test@abc.com"
    }
]
[]
[]
```

At the end you can see the last two sites that it iterated through are blank showing only the []

Everything up to this point is working as I expected. This is where I'm running into issues though. I'm trying to take that response in a further if statement that essentially ignores the results where the "resources" block is empty [] but adds the sid that was used from the call where there actually is data. My problem is that I'm still getting all 4 sid no matter how I do it.

When I use this:

```
site_ids_with_alerts = []
if smtp_json['resources'] != None:
    site_ids_with_alerts.append(sid)
    print(site_ids_with_alerts)
```

I still get a full list of [6, 5, 7, 1]

I was **EXPECTING** to get [6, 5]

I have also tried these below as well but every time I get the same results:

```
site_ids_with_alerts = []
site_ids_with_alerts = [sid if smtp_json['resources'] != "[]" else None]
```

```
if smtp_json['resources'] == None:
    None    
else:
    site_ids_with_alerts.append(sid)
```

```
if smtp_json['resources'] == '[]':
    None    
else:
    site_ids_with_alerts.append(sid)
```

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with my if statement looking at the JSON of a blank value.

When I run this:

`if smtp_json['resources'] == '':
 site_ids_with_alerts.append(sid)`

I get a blank list []

Answer (score 0):

The issue was how I was working with the empty value in JSON. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482047/checking-if-json-key-is-empty)

So I changed the code to look like this:

```
if not len(smtp_json['resources']) == 0:
    site_ids_with_alerts.append(sid)
```

Which gives me the list I wanted of [6,5]